# Utterly bewildered by JS 'arguments' peculiarity

Tags: javascript

I have this call:

```
function del(Model, modelName, model_id, req, res, next, cb) {

    if(req.query.optimisticDelete){
        optimisticDelete(arguments);
    }
    else{
        pessimisticDelete(arguments);
    }
}
```

the problem of course, is that the arguments aren't passed correctly to the optimisticDelete and pessimisticDelete functions.

in an ideal JS world, this might work, but I can easily see why it doesn't.

But it doesn't take away from that fact that I just didn't want to type all the arguments out for each call, and in fact I wanted to omit the arguments in the del function signature also, so this would be the most ideal situation, although I need a reference to the req object, which I am now missing:

```
  function del() {

        if(req.query.optimisticDelete){
            optimisticDelete(arguments);
        }
        else{
            pessimisticDelete(arguments);
        }
    }
```

but of course, when arguments is passed, it does not seem to magically separate into separate arguments.

And also, this doesn't work either:

```
function del(Model, modelName, model_id, req, res, next, cb) {

    if(req.query.optimisticDelete){
        optimisticDelete(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
    else{
        pessimisticDelete(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
}
```

if you understand what I am trying to do, please let me know if it's possible and how,

Comment: `optimisticDelete.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));`

Comment: @BenTaber You don't need to convert `arguments` to an array before using it with `apply`.

Comment: Reading up on what `arguments` are would be a great start to this question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments and then searching previous questions would be the best followup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `optimisticDelete` with a **single** argument, which is an `arguments` special object that contains all the arguments to the original call. If you want to spread them out, you need to use apply:

```
optimisticDelete.apply(null, arguments);
```

It's not necessary to convert `arguments` to an array first. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) says:

> You can also use `arguments` for the argsArray parameter. arguments is a local variable of a function. It can be used for all unspecified arguments of the called object. Thus, you do not have to know the arguments of the called object when you use the `apply` method. You can use `arguments` to pass all the arguments to the called object.

Comment: According to ECMAScript 2015, [*Function.prototype.apply*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply) will convert *arguments* to a List, which seems to be a much simpler structure than an Array. So a good reason to pass *arguments* as–is is to not waste time converting it to an Array that will be converted to a List anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems. First, the `arguments` object is weird, but it's not *that* weird. Nothing magically turns into a parameter list across a simple function call. There is, however, `Function.prototype.apply`, which is ultimately what you want.

First however you'll want to turn `arguments` into a plain array:

```
var plainArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Or, if you care about runtime efficiency:

```
var plainArgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
  plainArgs[i] = arguments[i];
```

(*Note* — this step may not be necessary, but passing the `arguments` object out of a function tends to make optimizers throw up their little hands and give up on your functions.)

(*Another note* — totally ignore this stuff about passing `arguments` to `.apply()` being bad. I'm wrong.)

With that out of the way, you can use `.apply()`:

```
    optimisticDelete.apply(null, plainArgs);
```

The `.apply()` function expects its second argument to be an array. That array becomes the individual arguments to the function. The first argument to `.apply()` is the value you'd like `this` to take on in the function call; since you were calling `optimisticDelete()` "naked" in the original code, I passed `null`, but you can pass whatever you want.

Comment: You don't have to convert it to an array first.

Comment: @Barmar are you sure about that? I have a reptile-brain memory of having to do that, but maybe that was Netscape 4 or something. (And you certainly do have to do it if you don't want V8 to bail on optimization.)

Comment: I quoted the paragraph about this in my answer.

Comment: While the syntax of `apply()` is almost identical to that of `call()`, the fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an argument list, while `apply()` accepts a single array of arguments.

Comment: @Barmar OK then, I'm convinced. However I still try to keep `arguments` from being passed out of my functions, maybe because in cases like this it's often something kind-of low-level that may get called a lot.

Comment: @Sphvn yes, that is certainly true.

Comment: @Sphvn the problem is that the semantics of the `arguments` object are weird in that the indexed elements of `arguments` are aliases for the actual parameters of a function, so it makes static analysis kind-of impossible. If you pass `arguments` to another function, V8 simply will not attempt to optimize your function at all. I suspect that other optimizers behave the same way for the same reasons.

Comment: @Sphvn [here is an interesting article on the topic.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)

Comment: @Sphvn digressing from the topic, but it seems that `try ... catch` also cause V8 to drop your functions from optimization consideration!

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for link! A topic of great interest that I have been wanting to learn about :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE That article is just about V8, but given the highly competitive and yet collaborative nature of JavaScript runtime/optimization developers, I would be very surprised to learn that the other runtime systems are much different.

Comment: Valid point. Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: @Pointy, interesting point in the article https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#what-is-safe-arguments-usage, specifically, `Never use arguments directly without .length or [i] (STRICTLY x.apply(y, arguments) is ok, nothing else is , e.g. .slice. Function#apply is special)` Wouldnt that mean that using `apply` like in Barmars answer wouldnt hurt optimization?

Comment: @AmmarCSE yes it would imply that my entire line of argument here has been completely wrong :) Live and learn.

Comment: @Pointy, heh, trust me, I have learned much more than you today :) , thanks again

Comment: @Pointy, instead of doing the for loop, wouldn't it be better to rely on the array slice api and do something like this? var plainArgs = [].slice.call(arguments)

Comment: @KumarM Well though I was wrong about `.apply()`, it's *generally* true that passing `arguments` out of a function causes the optimizer to give up on optimization. Read that github link I posted a few comments above this. The `.apply()` function is special, but others are not.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the link. Makes sense.

Comment: @Pointy—in mathematics (and hence computing), a *general* solution is one that works everywhere (e.g. general theory of relativity), so you probably mean *usually*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG yea this was not a good question for me